# Url images into collection View

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, swift3

I am trying to fetch images from url into my collection view. the number of images that can be shown depends on the array count.

Here is my code:

```
class CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var searchBox: UITextField!


var imageArray:[String] = []


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

    let link =  "https://www.googleapis.com/my_link_is_here"        
    guard let url = URL(string: link) else {

        print("Error: cannot create URL")
        return

    }

    let request = URLRequest(url: url)

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in

        guard error == nil else {

            print("error calling GET on /todos/1")
            print(error!)
            return
        }

        do{

            guard let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? [String : Any] else {

                print("\(error?.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }

            //print("The todo is: " + json.description)                                                
            guard let todotitle = json["items"] as? [Any] else {
                print("Could not get todo title from JSON")
                return
            }

            let arrcnt = todotitle.count


            var i = 0

            while (i < arrcnt){

                guard let todotitle1 = todotitle[i] as? [String: Any] else {
                    print("Could not get todo title1 from JSON")
                    return
                }


                guard let todotitle2 = todotitle1["image"] as? [String : Any] else {
                    print("Could not get todo title2 from JSON")
                    return
                }

                guard let todotitle3 = todotitle2["thumbnailLink"] as? String else {

                // continue
                print("Could not get todo title3 from JSON")
                 return

               }

               self.imageArray.append(todotitle3)

                print(self.imageArray)

                i += 1

            }                                                
        }catch{
            print("error trying to convert data to JSON")
            return
        }

        }.resume()

}



/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

// MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource

override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}


override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of items
    return self.imageArray.count
}
```

The problem is when I write "return self.imageArray.count" it returns nil. It takes the initialised value of the array that is an empty array. How can count the final array after it has been appended.

Comment: Can you show the declaration of imageArray?

Comment: class CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

    
    @IBOutlet weak var searchBox: UITextField!
    
    
    var imageArray:[String] = []
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

Comment: Never add your code in comment, instead of that edit your question.

Comment: It has been done..

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reload the `collectionView` on main thread after your `while` loop. Also you can reduce your code by making, single `guard` statement instead of multiple and use for loop instead of while, so whole code would be like this.

```
do{

    guard let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? [String : Any] else {

        print("\(error?.localizedDescription)")
        return
    }

    //print("The todo is: " + json.description)
    guard let array = json["items"] as? [[String : Any]] else {
        print("Could not get todo title from JSON")
        return
    }
    for dic in array {
        guard let imageDic = dic["image"] as? [String : Any], let thumbnailLink = imageDic["thumbnailLink"] as? String else {
            print("Could not get thumbnailLink")
            return
        }
        self.imageArray.append(thumbnailLink)
    }
    //Now you need to reload the collectionView on main thread.
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: only by reloading the collection view?

Comment: @GauravKapur Welcome mate :)

Comment: @GauravKapur Hey please accept the answer now after that it is works for you.